# Why I obtain this IOExceptio (Failed to decode stream) when I try to read from a Base64InputStream objet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, inputstream, ioexception

I have a **Base64InputStream** object and I have to read it but I obtain an exception. I do in this way:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(is);

int chunk = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
int bytesRead = -1;

OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while ((bytesRead = base64InputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

The problems occur when it try to perform this operation:

```
bytesRead = base64InputStream.read(buffer)
```

because the following exception is thrown:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to decode stream
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is that the bytes aren't properly encoded. Can you properly decode them by another means, e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: The IOException indicates there's something fundamentally wrong with the source data i.e. `byteArray`. Make sure it's not empty